# Scala Type Alias In Object

Tags: scala, object, types

I have an Object that has some type alias definitions:

```
case class MyCaseClass(someType: SomeType)
object MyObject extends SomeType {

  type SomeType = Int => Boolean
}
```

IntelliJ tells me that I have to import SomeType so that my case class can see it, but later the compiler is not happy and complains about illegal cyclic reference on the import statements. I have a couple of other objects that are declared as below:

```
object MyModule {
 object Obj1 { ... }
 object Obj2 { ... }
 object Obj3 { ... }
}
```

Each of those Obj's refer to the type alias defined in MyObject.

Is there a best practice to encapsulate the types? Should I move them in a trait or would that be considered an abuse? Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You object `MyObject` tries to inherit from a type that itself defines.

```
object MyObject extends SomeType {
  type SomeType = Int => Boolean
}
```

So, the first thing to do is define it at least outside `MyObject`:

```
type SomeType = Int => Boolean
object MyObject extends SomeType {
  def apply(v1: Int): Boolean = ???
}
```

Now, as scarce the information in your question is, I'd suggest you think a bit about your design. Identify where `SomeType` is referenced, where it needs to be visible. After that you could, for example, put it into a *package object* at a package level where it is visible to all referencing parties.